# Getting value in footer template from code behind-Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="pde">
<HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="literal1"></asp:Literal>
</ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="literal2"></asp:Literal></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now in literal2 I want to get the value from code behind.But I am not able to get the literal2 in code behind.Any idea how to get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access it by accessing the last `RepeaterItem` in your repeater which will be your footer.  Then do a search, using `FindControl`, on the `RepeaterItem` for any control you are looking for.

Using your example above do:

```
Literal controlYouWant = pde.Controls[pde.Controls.Count - 1].FindControl("literal2") as Literal;
```

You can break down the statements to:

```
// This will get you the footer
RepeaterItem item = pde.Controls[pde.Controls.Count - 1];
// From here you finds any control you want within the RepeaterItem.
Literal controlYouWant = item.FindControl("literal2") as Literal;
```

Comment: above statement pde.Controls[pede.Controls.Count-1].FindControl...is throwing an exception...I wonder because in my footertemplate I have like this
<FooterTemplate></li><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="literal2"/></div></FooterTemplate>

but i tried pde.Controls.Count-2...its also not working exception

Comment: I don't think that the other stuff in your template should matter.  I tested it with the same HTML that you just posted with the `</li>` and `</div>` and it still works fine.  Make sure you are binding to a `Datasource` with at least one item.  Break each item into a seperate line of code and debug from there to see exactly what is failing and post back.

Comment: Yah I got it,thanks a lot....mistake was i was doing this before binding data item into repeater so thats why there were no controls at that time and it was showing error.I need to use it after I do DataBind in repeater ....Wokrs perfectly...Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

First search through items in repeater and only take the footer item type and discard the           others. Take a look to the following code.

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in repeterName.Controls) 
{ 
    if (item.ItemType != ListItemType.Footer) continue; 
    var lblMyLabel = ((Label)item.FindControl("lblMyLabel")); 
    lblMyLabel.Text = "I found it!!!"; 
}
```